# solr filter query field type

Tags: solr, latency

I have a field named `"disabled"` which is `multivalued`. I will be running a filter query on this field which will basically search for a specific value on this field i.e. `fq=disabled:I`
I can map the value `"I"` to an integer and store  the corresponding integers into solr and do filter query based on integers.

So I wanted to know if it is better to store the field as `solr.trieInt` or  `solr.strField` type is better from a performance point of view?

Answer (score 0):

You will not notice any difference. If you were going to run range queries, then it might be more efficient to store it in a Int field, but for a simple lookup, it will not make a difference.

Note too, that 'trie' versions of numeric are not the latest ones, there are [Point based numeric types](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Field+Types+Included+with+Solr) that seem to be even better.